# R - Render multiple plots on single page of Shiny app

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to arrange multiple charts on **shiny** app. I am trying to plot 2 pie charts and a ggplot2 chart.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(gridExtra)

par(mfrow = c(2,2))    

z=data.frame(x=1:10, y=11:20)
pie(z$x,z$y)
pie(z$x,z$y)
ggplot(z, aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.3)
```

I tried with grid.arrange but it only render ggplot chart. I tried to to render these three plot using `grid.arrange`, then it return error message **input must be grobs!** Please help to render these three on single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what you want it to look like but here's an example how to combine your three plots:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(grid)
require(gridBase)

z=data.frame(x=1:10, y=11:20)

# setup everything
plot.new()
gl <- grid.layout(2,2)
vp.1 <- viewport(layout.pos.col = 1, layout.pos.row = 1)
vp.2 <- viewport(layout.pos.col = 2, layout.pos.row = 1)
vp.3 <- viewport(layout.pos.col = c(1,2), layout.pos.row = 2)
pushViewport(viewport(layout=gl))

# First plot
pushViewport(vp.1)
par(new = TRUE, fig = gridFIG(), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
pie(z$x,z$y)
popViewport()

# Second plot
pushViewport(vp.2)
par(new = TRUE, fig = gridFIG(), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
pie(z$x,z$y)
popViewport(1)

# Your ggplot
pushViewport(vp.3)
p<-ggplot(z, aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.3)
print(p, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport(2)
```

**NOTE:** I do not recommend using pie charts. [See this example](http://static4.businessinsider.com/image/51bf1e9becad048c0a000002-620-/screen%20shot%202013-06-17%20at%2010.34.08%20am.png)

Comment: Thanks Mehndi, this solve my half problem, I tried to add another chart on the same code after tweaking it. I change vp.3 <- viewport(layout.pos.col = 1, layout.pos.row = 2) and add vp.4 <- viewport(layout.pos.col = 2, layout.pos.row = 2). It returns **cannot pop the top-level viewport ('grid' and 'graphics' output mixed?)**

Comment: did you add a ggplot or another pie chart? because the latter requires you to set `par()`. And did you set `pushViewport(vp.4)` and `popViewport(3)`?

Comment: I added ggplot and set pushViewport(vp.4) and popViewport(3). code I added was `pushViewport(vp.4)
par(new = TRUE, fig = gridFIG(), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
p1<-ggplot(z, aes(x,y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.3)
print(p1, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport(3)`

Comment: I am facing another problem while using ggmap with the above code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28935768/r-shiny-error-pops-up-while-using-ggmap. whenever, I am trying to display map using print function using your code, it generates an error.